# pyqt open windows using mvc-pattern

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to use the mvc-pattern to structure the program I am working on right now. I ran into a question while writing the controller part:
I have a button on the main window which opens a second window. With the help of other topics I found a working solution to split this process essentially in two functions within the controller like so:

```
# Controller function
class WtfCtrl:
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.mainwindow = view
        self.connect_header_btns()

    # Here I connect the buttons of the main window   
    def connect_header_btns(self):
        self.mainwindow.infoScreen.clicked.connect(partial(self.show_info))

    # Here I show the info window
    def show_info(self):
        self.info_window = InfoWindow()
        self.info_window.show()
```

InfoWindow() is the actual class where I define the Infowindow. Everything works as I want it to but yet I feel like this is not the best way to achieve my goal. I was thinking about using a lambda function or something similar to do the same stuff with a single line of code.

Do you know if this is possible and if so how to write this.

Comment: Keep the code as is. Using a lambda will just make it less readable with no performance benefit.

Comment: Ok thank you :-) I just added antoher window to the code and it doesn't seem too bad anymore. I can see the benefit of the split now.